# Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body? Why can't I return?

Tags: javascript, eslint

What is wrong with the following? ESLIST is giving the error: `Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body`

```
  myFunIs = () => {
    return parser(this.state.myParam, 'color');
  }
```

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 4):

> This is intended behavior. If return is the only statement inside the body of an arrow function, you do not need block statement

```js
 myFunIs = () => parser(this.state.myParam, 'color');
```